# wpf listview - show real name instead of id

Tags: c#, wpf, class

I did make a class:

```
public class VerzekeringDossier
{
    public VerzekeringDossier()
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DossierNummer { get; set; }
    public int Gebouw { get; set; }
    public string Adres { get; set; }
    public string Schadelijder { get; set; }
    public string SchadeVeroorzaker { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
class Gebouw
{
    public Gebouw()
    {
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string GebouwNaam { get; set; }
}
```

Verzekeringdossier table:
[image]

Gebouw table:

[image]

And my listview looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, in table gebouw, there is the id, but i want ti change it to the name of gebouw with the correct id. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Use sql join to read the related data out gebouw and include name from there in your list of columns.https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: I was thinking about that, but i want aslo be possible to edit it and in the edit "listbox" i want a list with all Gebouw (=buildings in english)

Comment: In which case, read them in separately and fill a collection with id and name then use a comboboxcolumn. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26347.wpf-combobox-binding-in-datagrid.aspx

Answer (score 0):

more than a hint I can give you a track.
Your first class contains an int for the id that is public, it could be way more interesting to have a private field which contains the id and a public acces for the object Gebouw.

```
...    
private int _id {get;set;}
public Gebouw gebouw => method_to_get_Gebouw(_id);
...
```

And to display the name you can simply override the toString method in the Gebouw class

```
...
public override string ToString()
    {
        return GebouwNaam;
    }
...
```

Hope it can help you !